# Organize big lists structure and jquery to fadeIn items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have three list like this in the site i´m developing:

```
    <ul class="sublist first_sublist_b">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 15</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Each "li" would fadeIn a hidden div like this one:

```
<div class="product_box">
    <h3>Item Title 1</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that I don´t know what would be the **best way to structure this**, keeping in mind that the three lists have 15 items, so there would be 45 items in total. Should I place every **item div inside every "li"**? how can I work this out with jquery?

Edit: product_box div will appear below the list, not in a modal window or inside the "li".

Comment: Use jQuery accordion for these type of things

Comment: Check out the jQuery Modal plugin.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that the div will appear below the list, not in a modal or not inside the "li" :)

Comment: Just have one div after all the ul's. This div will get populated depending on the li clicked. You don't really need three divs do you ? And where do you intend to pull the description from ?

Comment: I see, well I was  thinking before the programming to show it to the client, to show him several items, after that it would be one div getting the info from wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="sublist first_sublist_b">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Title 2</a></li>
    .....

</ul>

<div class="product_box_wrapper">
    <div class="product_box">Item description 1</div>
    <div class="product_box">Item description 2</div>
    ......
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".first_sublist_b a").on("click", function() {
        var index = $(this).parent().index(); // li index in ul;

        $(".product_box_wrapper .product_box").eq(index).fadeIn(500);
        /**
        * You can add fadeOut to the siblings:
        * .siblings().fadeOut();
        *
        * $(".product_box_wrapper .product_box").eq(index).fadeIn(500).siblings().fadeOut();;
        */
    });
});
```